# Which JavaFX classes interact to render controls?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Every control has a skin, but how are the skins rendered on stage? Yes, the main CSS file, the Scene Graph and the Prism Rendering Thread are there, but I want to know which classes do what part on rendering. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more, but Node, Scene, CssStyleHelper, the toolkit interface (QuantumToolkit), QuantumRenderer, the glass scene (ViewScene), ViewPainter, PaintCollector, PaintRenderJob, PGNode, Graphics, BaseContext, and VertexBuffer all do their part in rendering controls.

I just thought I would share it in case somebody else would need it, or in case I need to be corrected.

It starts with a pulse() on the QuantumToolkit, which calls PaintCollector's renderAll(), which then calls repaint() on ViewScene. ViewScene adds a PaintRenderJob to the QuantumToolkit which submits the job to an ExecutorService via QuantumRenderer.

PaintRenderJob has its ViewPainter which is a Runnable that has a PGNode. On one implementation of ViewPainter, the PGNode contained in ViewPainter gets drawn by letting PGNode call draw on its Graphic object.

The graphic determines the manner of drawing, and then flushes to the VertexBuffer via the BaseContext. Flushing to the VertexBuffer involves a native method called drawQuads(int).

For the part of the Node, Scene, and CssStyleHelper, they are there to tell which need to be repainted. The telling is done via listeners.

In FX2, there was a  PrismPen that begins and ends the drawing session.